# Invalid Object Name in mssql 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, schema

We currently have an issue with our MSSQL 2005 database. We've recently undergone a migration from windows server 2003 to 2008. SQL Server has remained as 2005. I'm using SQL Server Management Studio to work on.

All the tables in the database follow the format: [SCHEMA].[TABLE_NAME]

When I enter the SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM [table_name]
```

I get the error message: Invalid object name '[table_name]'.

If I type in:

```
SELECT * FROM [schema].[table_name]
```

This works fine. The username we log into the database with owns the schema which is prepended to all the table names.

The problem is, we have 3rd party companies which have software which exports data from the database. 2 companies have now tried to run their exporters, however are getting the error 'Invalid object name'. The software is logging in with the username which owns the schema.

My question is exactly the same as this one I've found on the internet:
http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=99802

However the answer on that question seems to be full of keywords rather than actual sentences which makes it very hard to understand.

If anyone could help, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Phil

Comment: Always use the schema prefix when creating and referencing objects. ALWAYS. Tell your 3rd party company they don't get a pass. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix.aspx

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand Unfortunately need these exporter programs. They are a requirement of our organisation. They used to work before we upgraded our network even without the schema prefix, but they now don't. Is there not a way to automatically prepend the default schema to the table when the user logs into the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the default schema for the 3rd party's username to the schema their un-prefixed references should point to:

```
ALTER USER foo WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [bar];
```

(This is different from owning the schema.)

And tell them to write software correctly. In SQL Server you should always be specifying the schema name, even if you always use `dbo`.

Comment: Thanks for the response Aaron. I have performed this query, however its still coming up with Invalid Object Name when you enter an unprefixed table name.

Comment: And you're sure you adjusted the user name that the user is connecting as? Have you checked that `EXECUTE AS` is not being used? Have you checked the actual schema the table belongs to? These are just hacks, by the way. If someone moves one of those tables to a different schema, your app breaks again. The *fix* is to stop accepting crap from 3rd parties.